# error: 'org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException'

Tags: spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa, rest, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I was making a rest api for an application easy-notes using spring boot. But I was facing some errors while running it on eclipse ide. The link for my project is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RnyZI9r9l5IVHtUT1j1N5p2krRqcvDUw?usp=sharing

For reference this is the link of the console-log:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_kWy9SSomF75dKqTdd2lG3zgwKJkmiJO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have given my solution , can you check if this resolves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your code first make the following change
in your application.properties file change

```
apring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Then You model class here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RMpFXCUIhkFpcH8vreAnbdPHJgs1_tCl

change

```java
public class Note {

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "courses")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
             allowGetters = true)
    public class note implements Serializable {
...
```

to

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class Note implements Serializable {
...
```

So complete correct file becomes as below:

```java
package com.hp.easynotes.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class Note implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    private String title;
    private String content;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date CreatedAt;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date UpdatedAt;


    //Getters & Setters

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }


    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return CreatedAt;
    }


    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        CreatedAt = createdAt;
    }


    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return UpdatedAt;
    }


    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        UpdatedAt = updatedAt;
    }


}
```